# Running a mv command on large amount of data caused disappearance of other folders

Tags: data-recovery, grep, mv

I messed up by running a mv command on the entire contents of an old external drive to my Desktop without making a destination folder first.

I ran

```
sudo mv /my/external/path/* /home/myself/Desktop/
```

when instead I should have made a directory on Desktop first.

I wasn't thinking, and my Desktop was filling up behind my full screen terminal while I walked away unbeknownst to me. I had 3 important folders on it (School, Dev Projects, and CODE), all of them with many subdirectories. Well, they're gone, and I cannot find them.
To compound the situation, I didn't realize that my computer didn't have enough space to complete the job, so not everything was copied.

If I did not manually delete these folders, where could they have gone? I checked /home/myself/.local/share/Trash/files and found nothing.

I ran

```
grep -nr "Some_Folder_or_File_Names"
```

on the newer external I copied to, and found nothing.

If these folders are lost, I just lost over a year of development projects and school material.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the `/home/myself/Desktop`-folder.

Comment: Your `grep` searches the text `Some_Folder_or_File_Names` ***whithin*** the files. It doesn't match filenames. Try `find . -name "*Some_Folder_or_File_Names*"` instead.

Comment: Did that too after posting this. Nothing. Even did ls -a.

Comment: Ok tried the "find" command. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted and voila!
That was weird. O.o

Comment: **Warning:** Self-answer!  Do not close answer!  VTC Q instead!